What's so special about quotient spaces?
I've just started studying normed spaces and topological vector spaces in my functional analysis textbook and they've introduced quotients of normed spaces, and I keep wondering why these spaces are worth studying - what makes them so interesting? It's not the first time I've seen quotient spaces before, but every textbook/resource I've used hasn't really given a clear motivation for studying these particular spaces, so I'm asking what properties of quotient spaces make them worth studying?

Quotients are useful because of maps. It might be hard to visualize for vector spaces, but consider the quotient $q:[0, 1]\to S^1$ where $0$ and $1$ get identified. If you have a map $f:[0, 1]\to X$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$ then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q^{-1}:S^1\to X$ is continuous. This is for topological spaces, but something similar should hold for topological vector spaces. Of course they also allow you to construct new spaces, which is important

It is quite hard to explain why quotient spaces are important. It's like asking why metric spaces are important? Or why groups are important? Quotient space are so common, appear almost everywhere. It would be hard to overestimate their importance.

Quotient spaces are as important as subspaces. For groups, we have subgroups and quotient groups (factor groups), for algebras we have subalgebras and quotient algebras etc. You could ask as well, why for integers we have not only addition, but also multiplication. What's so special about multiplication of integers?
